# Can I specify a function signature with the elements of a struct?

Tags: c++, esp-idf

Let's say I have a struct...

```
typedef struct _TestMessage { 
    int32_t a_count; 
    int32_t b_count; 
    char message[16]; 
} TestMessage;
```

And I want to define a function, where the signature matches the elements in that struct...

so, what I want is...

```
void encodeTestMessage(int32_t a_count, int32_t b_count, char* message)
{
...
}
```

...but I'd like to get to that signature by telling c++ about the struct, so that if it changes in the future my signatures change with them.

Is this even possible? (I'm looking extra suspiciously at that `message` argument...)

I'm using C++ 17 on this project.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: Why not just pass the struct?

Comment: ... by const ref, if needs be.

Comment: Do you mean [pointer-to-member](https://godbolt.org/z/YqG3sMYWc)? Maybe it's the case here, although judging by your question only it seems superfluous.
Please elaborate more on what you need, possibly describe your exact use case.

Comment: Why not just do `void encodeTestMessage(TestMessage& msg);`?

Comment: I suspect that this could be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please explain why you are asking for this.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 ways I can think of;

1. Using macros; which is not very modern
2. Using reflections; hopefully in the future
3. Using SFINAE (it would be awesome if you used C++20 concepts though):

This is gets you where you want it, but `is_constructible` is not exactly what you wanted. There will be some unfortunate side effects as some other types will be allowed as well such as a `_TestMessage` instantiation itself which uses the default copy constructor.

```cpp
template <typename ...Args,
std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<_TestMessage, Args...>, bool> = true>
void encodeTestMessage(Args...args)
{

}
```

But of course the question itself begs the question "why not just use _TestMessage instead"!

Also the class name `_TestMessage` is not a valid C++ identifier because it starts with an underscore and a capital letter.